# Missing pad tCream

Tags: eaglecad, surface-mount, footprint

I've just finished my first component footprint and then I figured out that there is a pad without tCream, which I guess it is generated automatically.
What could be went wrong?
By the way, does it has importance?

Thanks in advance,

[image: Pin 1 without tCream]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the package in the library editor, then right click on the pad in question and select `Properties...`, there should be a check box for `Cream`. This has probably become unchecked hence there is no box created on the cream layer. Once you re-enable it a box on the tCream layer will be generated.

---

If you are already using the footprint, you will then in the Layout window need to go to `Library->Update All` (alternatively `Library->Update...` and select just the library you are interested in) to pull the updates into your board design.

---

In terms of importance, it depends on if you are hand soldering the board or using a reflow approach (e.g. having it machine assembled). The `tCream` and `bCream` layers are used to indicate where solder paste will be placed when machine assembling - or more accurately when a solder paste stencil is made.