# in Eagle, how to exclude SMD pad from the tCream layer

Tags: eaglecad, surface-mount

In Eagle, how do you exclude SMD pads from the tCream layer such that in gtp there is no pad there?

Comment: related: [Missing pad tCream](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197628/missing-pad-tcream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the component and disable cream in the package editor.

[image: eagle cream library package editor]

Notice that this will remove cream from all designs/components using this **package** when you run library update.